# Uncaught TypeError: $loadableItems.ensureLoad is not a function at Masonry.ensureLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm receiving the following JS error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: $loadableItems.ensureLoad is not a function
    at Masonry.ensureLoad (Essenza-built.js?ver=4be1690…:1)
    at Masonry.<anonymous> (Essenza-built.js?ver=4be1690…:1)
    at Object.d [as success] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at y (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
```

This JS excerpt is included below. The masonry code block seems to be the issue. I think it has something to do with the scope of the variables and functions but I'm not sure. It could also be related to the the order in which jQuery is being loaded. I would really appreciate any assistance with this issue.

```
6: [function(require, module, exports) {
        var $ = jQuery;
        var Masonry = function($holder, objects_query, maxWidth, minColumns, ajaxFunction, postID) {
            $(document).ready($.proxy(function($) {
                this.$holder = $holder;
                this.$loading_more = $(".loading_more");
                this.objects_query = objects_query;
                this.postID = postID;
                this.$fullDiv = $(".easyBackground");
                this.itemsShown = 0;
                this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
                this.minColumns = minColumns;
                this.loadingFurnace = false;
                this.firstFurnace = true;
                this.hasMore = true;
                this.currentNumber = 0;
                var holderWidth = this.$holder.width();
                var numberOfColumns = this.getNumberColumns(holderWidth);
                this.number = numberOfColumns * 7;
                this.offset = 0;
                this.ajaxFunction = ajaxFunction;
                this.loadFurnace();
                $(window).resize($.proxy(this.window_resize_timeout, this));
                $(window).bind("resize_grid", $.proxy(this.window_resize_timeout, this))
            }, this))
        };
        Masonry.prototype = {
            loadFurnace: function() {
                if (this.loadingFurnace || !this.hasMore || this.$holder.length == 0) return;
                if (!this.firstFurnace) this.$loading_more.show();
                var objSend = "frontend=true&number=" + this.number + "&offset=" + this.offset + "&action=" + this.ajaxFunction + "&postId=" + this.postID + "&maxWidth=" + this.maxWidth;
                this.loadingFurnace = true;
                this.offset += this.number;
                if (WP_DEBUG) console.log("Trying to load " + this.number + " items");
                var startTime = (new Date).getTime();
                $.post(adminAjax, objSend, $.proxy(function(data, textStatus) {
                    var time = (new Date).getTime();
                    if (WP_DEBUG) console.log("Time: " + (time - startTime));
                    var $data = $(data);
                    this.$holder.append($data);
                    var number = this.$holder.find(this.objects_query).length - this.currentNumber;
                    this.currentNumber += number;
                    if (number < this.number) this.hasMore = false;
                    var objects = $(this.objects_query).css({
                        position: "absolute"
                    });
                    this.items = new Array;
                    objects.each($.proxy(function(index, item) {
                        var $item = $(item);
                        this.items.push($item)
                    }, this));
                    this.ensureLoad();
                    $(this).trigger("added")
                }, this))
            },
            ensureLoad: function() {
                var $loadableItems = this.$holder.find("img, .slider").not(".slider img");
                var num = $loadableItems.length;
                var counter = 0;
                var load_timeout;
                if (num > 0) {
                    load_timeout = setTimeout($.proxy(this.allElementsAreLoaded, this), 2e3);
                    $loadableItems.ensureLoad($.proxy(function() {
                        clearTimeout(load_timeout);
                        counter++;
                        if (WP_DEBUG) console.log("loaded " + counter + "/" + num);
                        if (counter == num && this.loadingFurnace) this.allElementsAreLoaded();
                        else load_timeout = setTimeout($.proxy(this.allElementsAreLoaded, this), 2e3)
                    }, this))
                } else this.allElementsAreLoaded()
            },
            allElementsAreLoaded: function() {
                this.loadingFurnace = false;
                this.resize();
                this.$holder.find(".slider").trigger("resizeSlider");
                this.resize();
                this.window_resize_timeout();
                this.$loading_more.hide();
                this.showItem();
                if (this.firstFurnace) {
                    this.firstFurnace = false;
                    $(window).unbind("scroll", $.proxy(this.onGridScroll, this));
                    $(window).scroll($.proxy(this.onGridScroll, this))
                }
                $(this).trigger("furnaceLoaded")
            },
            onGridScroll: function() {
                if (!this.hasMore) return;
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 500) {
                    this.loadFurnace()
                }
            },
            showItem: function() {
                clearTimeout(this.showItemsTimeout);
                if (this.items[this.itemsShown] != undefined) {
                    this.items[this.itemsShown++].addClass("appear");
                    if (this.itemsShown < this.items.length) this.showItemsTimeout = setTimeout($.proxy(this.showItem, this), 60)
                }
            },
            windowResized: function() {
                if (this.items == undefined) return;
                if (this.items.length > 0) this.resize()
            },
            window_resize_timeout: function() {
                clearTimeout(this.resize_timeout);
                this.resize_timeout = setTimeout($.proxy(this.windowResized, this), 200)
            },
            getNumberColumns: function(totalWidth) {
                var numColumns = 0;
                var w = this.maxWidth + 1;
                while (w > this.maxWidth) {
                    numColumns++;
                    w = totalWidth / numColumns
                }
                if (numColumns < this.minColumns) numColumns = this.minColumns;
                return numColumns
            },
            changedCategory: function(animateTranslation) {
                this.resize(animateTranslation === false ? false : true)
            },
            resize: function(animateTranslation) {
                if (this.loadingFurnace) return;
                var AvHeight = this.$fullDiv.height();
                var hasScrollbar = false;
                if (AvHeight < this.$holder.height()) hasScrollbar = true;
                var holderWidth = this.$holder.width();
                var numberOfColumns = this.getNumberColumns(holderWidth);
                var itemsWidth = Math.ceil(holderWidth / numberOfColumns);
                this.number = numberOfColumns * 7;
                var columnsHeight = [],
                    i = numberOfColumns;
                while (i--) {
                    columnsHeight[i] = 0
                }
                var counter = 0;
                $.each(this.items, $.proxy(function(index, item) {
                    if (item.is(":visible")) {
                        item.css({
                            width: itemsWidth + "px"
                        });
                        var itemHeight = Math.floor(item.height()) - 1;
                        var column = counter++;
                        while (column >= numberOfColumns) column -= numberOfColumns;
                        var top = columnsHeight[column];
                        var columnIt = 0;
                        var max = 0;
                        while (columnIt < numberOfColumns) {
                            if (columnsHeight[columnIt] > max) max = columnsHeight[columnIt];
                            columnIt++
                        }
                        var columnIt = 0;
                        var min = itemHeight / 2;
                        while (columnIt < numberOfColumns) {
                            if (max - columnsHeight[columnIt] > min) {
                                top = columnsHeight[columnIt];
                                column = columnIt;
                                min = max - columnsHeight[columnIt]
                            }
                            columnIt++
                        }
                        if (animateTranslation) item.stop().animate({
                            left: itemsWidth * column + "px",
                            top: top + "px"
                        }, 500, "easeOutExpo");
                        else item.css({
                            left: itemsWidth * column + "px",
                            top: top + "px"
                        });
                        if (column == numberOfColumns - 1) item.addClass("last");
                        else item.removeClass("last");
                        columnsHeight[column] += itemHeight
                    }
                }, this));
                var totalHeight = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < columnsHeight.length; i++)
                    if (columnsHeight[i] > totalHeight) totalHeight = columnsHeight[i];
                this.$holder.css("height", totalHeight + "px");
                if (AvHeight >= totalHeight && hasScrollbar) {
                    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                    this.$holder.css("height", AvHeight - 1 + "px");
                    this.resize(animateTranslation);
                    $(window).scrollTop(scroll);
                    return
                } else if (AvHeight < totalHeight && !hasScrollbar) {
                    this.resize(animateTranslation)
                }
                $(this).trigger("gridResize");
                this.$holder.find(".social_video").trigger("gridResize");
                this.$holder.find(".music_player").trigger("playerResize")
            }
        };
        module.exports = Masonry
    }, {}],
```